# How do I increase the speed of my ball movement, but keep the smooth animation

Tags: javascript

Right now, my ball moves very slowly, at 1px on w, a, s, or d click. I don't really want to do a setInterval function. I'm not sure what to do to make my ball move faster, but still at 1px for a second. Alternatively, maybe someone could show me how to make smooth ball movement but still at higher speeds, like 10px? Thanks a ton!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.screen.width
canvas.height = window.screen.height
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
r = 50;
var dx = 1;
var dy = -1;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

window.onkeypress = function(e) {


    console.log(e.keyCode)

    if (e.keyCode == 119) {

        function drawCircle() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        window.requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle)
        y += dy
    } else if (e.keyCode == 97) {

        function drawCircle() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        window.requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle)
        x -= dx
    } else if (e.keyCode == 115) {
        
        function drawCircle() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        window.requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle)
        y -= dy
    } else if (e.keyCode == 100) {
        
        function drawCircle() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        window.requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle)
        x += dx
    }
}


window.onload = function() {

}
```

Comment: The basic problem is the conditionally declared functions. Don't do that, declare the function only once, outside of the keypress handler (changing that to keydown handler might also speed up the script a bit).

Comment: I tried declaring the functions once outside of the keypress handler. I had 2 functions per key and declared them in the keypress handler, with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the key event listening from the animation loop. Here's a small OOP based code snippet, which stores the direction of the ball into a lookup table type object. When a key is pressed down, a direction is stored (as -1/1), when a key is released, the direction is marked as 0. The animation loop runs independently from the key events, and moves the ball based on the stored directions and `speed` property.

```js
// Mathematical constants
const dCorr = 1 / Math.sqrt(2),
  PI2 = Math.PI * 2;

class Game {
  constructor(cnvId, stKeys) {
    // Steering keys
    this.keys = stKeys;
    const negKeys = Object.keys(stKeys);
    this.lKey = negKeys[0];
    this.uKey = negKeys[1];
    this.rKey = negKeys[2];
    this.dKey = negKeys[3];

    // Ball parameters
    this.x = 100;
    this.y = 100;
    this.r = 50;
    this.speed = 6;

    // The game area
    this.cnv = document.querySelector(cnvId);
    this.ctx = this.cnv.getContext('2d');

    // this binding for contextless method calls
    this.keyDown = this.keyDown.bind(this);
    this.keyUp = this.keyUp.bind(this);
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
  }
  init() {
    const cnv = this.cnv;
    // Add events
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyUp);

    // Set game area
    cnv.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
    cnv.height = window.innerHeight - 20;

    // Start the animation
    this.animate();
    return this;
  }
  keyDown(e) {
    const key = e.code;
    if (!(this.keys.hasOwnProperty(key))) {return;} // Quit, not a steering key 
    this.keys[key] = (key === this.lKey || key === this.uKey) ? -1 : 1;
  }
  keyUp(e) {
    const key = e.code;
    if (!(this.keys.hasOwnProperty(key))) {return;} // Quit, not a steering key
    this.keys[key] = 0;
  }
  animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);

    // Calculate coordinates delta
    let dX = (this.keys[this.lKey] + this.keys[this.rKey]) * this.speed,
      dY = (this.keys[this.dKey] + this.keys[this.uKey]) * this.speed;
    // Diagonal speed correction
    if (dX && dY) {
      dX *= dCorr;
      dY *= dCorr;
    }

    // Calculate the coordinates
    this.x += dX;
    this.y += dY;

    // Move the ball
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.cnv.width, this.cnv.height);
    this.moveBall(this.x, this.y);
  }
  moveBall(x, y) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, this.r, 0, PI2);
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}

const game = new Game(
  '#cnv', // Unique selector for the canvas
  {KeyA: 0, KeyW: 0, KeyD: 0, KeyS: 0} // Steering keys, left/up/right/down 
).init();
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

This code doesn't contain border collision detection, but it's easy to add, see an example at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/za10fgoL/3/). Notice also, that [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) is deprecated, `KeyboardEvent.code` is used instead. OOP is not necessary, but it helps to reuse the code, and you can add as many canvases as you need to the same page and move the ball with different keys. The class also works as it is on any page when ever the page has a canvas with an unique property, which can be used as a CSS selector (class, id, data-* attribute etc.).

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I learned a ton. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You code is a complete re-write so I will give you an example using ES6 classes. Classes are great for this type of thing. In the snippet below I have one for the circle and one for the controller. You can create many instances of circle and controllers with just by using classes.

You can also use an animation function to draw/animate all of you objects on screen.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

//classes allow you to easily build the same object over and over
class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.color = "lightgrey"; //if you wanted to add a fillStyle
    this.dx = 0;
    this.dy = 0;
  }
  //draws the object
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  //updates anything related to the object
  update() {
    //increasingly adds 0.5 to the dy or dx
    if (controller1.up) {this.dy -= 0.5}; 
    if (controller1.right) {this.dx += 0.5};
    if (controller1.down) {this.dy += 0.5};
    if (controller1.left) {this.dx -= 0.5};
    //if dy or dx is being added to so will the x and y. If not then they are 0.
    this.x += this.dx;  
    this.y += this.dy;
    //Multiplying by a number less then 1 will prevent the object from gaining infinite speed and also cause the object to stop. Can be changed to anything below 1. This will also change how rigidly the circle comes to a stop. it can slide or absuplty stop.
    this.dx *= 0.9;
    this.dy *= 0.9;
    //calling the draw() in here so I don't have to call it in the animate loop. Either way works.
    this.draw(); 
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.up = false;
    this.right = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;
    
    let keyEvent = (e) => {
      //if the condition is true it will set up/down/left/right to the true or false. e.type will either be 'keyup' or 'keydown'.
      if (e.code == "KeyW") {this.up = e.type == 'keydown'};
      if (e.code == "KeyD") {this.right = e.type == 'keydown'};
      if (e.code == "KeyS") {this.down = e.type == 'keydown'};
      if (e.code == "KeyA") {this.left = e.type == 'keydown'};
      
    }
    addEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
    addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent);
    }
}

//Create instances of you classes
let circle1 = new Circle(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 50, 0, Math.PI*2);
//can add more circles if you want
//let circle2 = new Circle(100, 100, 20, 0, Math.Pi*2);
let controller1 = new Controller();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circle1.update();
  //can add circle2.draw() if you want the other circle to be staionary. 
  //circle2.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```